# Trouble Integrating SonarQube in Android Studio: Need Assistance

Tags: sonarqube, android-studio-3.0, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint, sonarqube5.1

I downloaded sonarcube from offical site. When selecting `StartServer` from

```
C:\sonarqube-10.3.0.82913\bin\windows-x86-64
```

it is opening the command prompt and automatically closes down.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OizyY.png)

I tried to run the server.
I am expecting y=to connect to localhost:9000 and show sonar dashboard.

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as image, use formatted text instead!

Comment: well i found the solution,if we run as administrator sonarqube server will load and will be up and runnig